# Laravel 5 using OR condition with BETWEEN

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hi can anyone help me building below query in laravel Eloquent i am really confuse in using **OR** condition with **between**

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE
existing_start BETWEEN $newSTart AND $newEnd OR
$newStart BETWEEN existing_start AND existing_end
```

i tried using like

```
whereBetween('existing_start',[$newSTart,$newEnd])
```

but have no idea how to use OR

Comment: Try adding parens around your between clauses.

Comment: look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49875190/3417144

Answer (score 12):

There is an `orWhereBetween` method available from the Query Builder, but it is undocumented in the [Query Builder Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#where-clauses). You can however find it in the [Laravel API Documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_orWhereBetween).

---

The explanations below assume that the variables have the following values:

```
$newStart = '1';
$newEnd = '10';
```

---

Unfortunatelly, using `orWhereBetween` for the second condition is not applicable in your case, because both `whereBetween` and `orWhereBetween` will check if a column value is between two input values. This is fine from your first condition since it checks if the  `existing_start` column value is between `$newStart` and `$newEnd`. So this is fine:

```
->whereBetween('existing_start', [$newStart, $newEnd])
```

As it will be compiled to:

```
WHERE `existing_start` BETWEEN '1' AND '10'
```

However your second condition wants to check if an input value from `$newStart` is between two column values `existing_start` and `existing_end`, and there is no Query Builder method that does that. So this will not work:

```
->orWhereBetween($newStart, ['existing_start', 'existing_end'])
```

Because it will be compiled to:

```
OR `1` BETWEEN 'existing_start' AND 'existing_end'
```

Notice the backticks `` ` `` around `1`, because of that MySQL will try to find a column named `1` and throw an error.

---

So the best option here is to use `orWhereRaw` with bindings like this:

```
DB::table('tbl')
  ->whereBetween('existing_start', [$newStart, $newEnd])
  ->orWhereRaw('? BETWEEN existing_start AND existing_end', [$newStart])
  ->get();
```

The `?` will be replaced by the value of `$newStart` which will be properly quoted and escaped to avoid SQL injection.

---

Or course there is always the option of having two grouped conditions that check the boundaries, which would be equivalent to your `BETWEEN` condition:

```
DB::table('tbl')
  ->whereBetween('existing_start', [$newStart, $newEnd])
  ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($newStart) {
      $query->where('existing_start', '<=', $newStart);
      $query->where('existing_end', '>=', $newStart);
  })->get();
```

Which will compile to:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl`
WHERE
  `existing_start` BETWEEN '1' AND '10' OR
  (`existing_start` <= '1' AND `existing_end` >= '1')
```

Comment: Thank you for the information I will try both way hope it will work

Answer (score 2):

You're right, you can use Eloquent's `whereBetween()`. For OR, you should use `orWhere()`:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#advanced-where-clauses

I'm not 100% sure if it'll work, but you can try this:

```
$data = DB::table('tbl')
        ->whereBetween('existing_start', [$newSTart, $newEnd])
        ->orWhere(function ($query) {
            $query->whereBetween($newStart, [existing_start, existing_end])
        })
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

This work for me.

```
    $sql->where(function ($query) {
        $query->whereBetween('start_date', ['2018-04-04', '2018-04-25']);
        $query->orWhereBetween('cancelled_at', ['2018-04-04', '2018-05-01']);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  $start_date_w1 = Carbon::now()->subDays(7)->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
  $end_date_w1 = Carbon::now()->subDays(7)->format('Y-m-d 23:59:59');
  $start_date_w2 = Carbon::now()->subDays(14)->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
  $end_date_w2 = Carbon::now()->subDays(14)->format('Y-m-d 23:59:59');
  $parents = AdoptiveParent::whereBetween('created_at', [$start_date_w1,$end_date_w1])
              ->orWhere(function ($query) use($start_date_w2,$end_date_w2) {
                  return $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$start_date_w2,$end_date_w2]);
              })
              ->get();
  return $parents;
```

this query will help you to find parents from **(Adaptive Parent Model)**, which are created before 7 and 14 days.
Check for you have used *$start_date_w2,$end_date_w2* parameter for subquery e.g. `->orWhere(function ($query) use($start_date_w2,$end_date_w2)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to group the parameters, adapt the example in the documentation

```php
DB::table('users')
            ->where('name', '=', 'John')
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->where('votes', '>', 100)
                      ->orWhere('title', '=', 'Admin');
            })
            ->get();
```