# Filters in laravel5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

In case I have filter users with location and date,I have written query like below

```
public function searchConsultants()
{
     $location = $request->get('location');
     $fromDate = $request->get('from_date');
     $toDate = $request->get('to_date');
     $data = DB::table('consultants')
    ->selectRaw('AVG(COALESCE(ratings.rating_for_manager, 0))as avg_rating, consultants.id,consultants.cunsultant_name,contact_number,location')
    ->where('location','LIKE','%'.$location.'%')
    ->whereBetween('date',[$fromDate,$toDate])
    ->leftJoin('ratings', 'ratings.consultant_id', 'consultants.id')
    ->groupBy('consultants.id')
    ->orderBy('avg_rating', 'DESC')
    ->get();
}
```

With above query I can get data but sometimes **I dont want to search with date** I want search only with location,

The problem in above query I must enter location and date to filter users,So How can I filter with only location or date.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35926066/5808894

Answer (score 0):

Use orWhere read it at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses

```
public function searchConsultants()
{
     $location = $request->get('location');
     $fromDate = $request->get('from_date');
     $toDate = $request->get('to_date');
     $data = DB::table('consultants')
    ->selectRaw('AVG(COALESCE(ratings.rating_for_manager, 0))as avg_rating, consultants.id,consultants.cunsultant_name,contact_number,location')
    ->where('location','LIKE','%'.$location.'%')
    ->orwhereBetween('date',[$fromDate,$toDate])
    ->leftJoin('ratings', 'ratings.consultant_id', 'consultants.id')
    ->groupBy('consultants.id')
    ->orderBy('avg_rating', 'DESC')
    ->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
public function searchConsultants()
{
     $location = $request->get('location');
     $fromDate = $request->get('from_date');
     $toDate = $request->get('to_date');
     $data = DB::table('consultants')
    ->selectRaw('AVG(COALESCE(ratings.rating_for_manager, 0))as avg_rating, consultants.id,consultants.cunsultant_name,contact_number,location')
    ->whereBetween('date',[$fromDate,$toDate])
    ->orWhere('location','LIKE','%'.$location.'%')    
    ->leftJoin('ratings', 'ratings.consultant_id', 'consultants.id')
    ->groupBy('consultants.id')
    ->orderBy('avg_rating', 'DESC')
    ->get();
}
```

Comment: Hi there. We have had a glorious freeze for at least a year in the addition of "hope this helps" and "this may work for you" to your posts. I recall quite clearly that you continued to add them until a diamond moderator removed a couple, and at that point you agreed to desist. Something seems to have changed on your side in the last week or so. Nevertheless, technical writing is still preferred here, and I plan still to remove them. I would therefore be enormously grateful if you did not give me more work to do `:-)`.

Comment: Presently you have 376 posts that need clean-up in this fashion, and I hope we can bring that down to zero eventually.