# laravel query whereBetween doesn't work

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, date, laravel-query-builder

Here is my Laravel query.

```
$fromdate = '2018-04-09';
$todate = '2018-04-28';
$dt = array($fromdate, $todate);
return DB::table('leaves')
  ->select('leaveId')
  ->whereBetween('from', [$dt[0], $dt[1]])
  ->orWhereBetween('to', [$dt[0], $dt[1]])
  ->get();
```

my db rows

```
'11', 'ckkl;kghhjgkgvjkvvb,,kkkkhhhhh', '2018-03-29', '2018-04-21', '2018-04-22', 'Sam User', NULL, '2018-03-29 10:52:48', '2018-03-29 10:52:48', '2', '8', '1'
'10', 'pjp\'', '2018-03-29', '2018-04-11', '2018-04-12', 'test user', NULL, '2018-03-29 10:50:28', '2018-03-29 10:50:28', '1', '8', '1'
```

It seems it doesn't check the `whereBetween` clause. It only returns leaveId. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: `only return leaveIds`-> you are selecting only `leaveIds` column so your query will give that output only. what else you think it will give you?

Comment: I've update code. Yes, but It doesn't check wherebetween

Comment: when you say it returns leaveID you mean it returns all the data or what?

Comment: @max  :- check this answer:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35926066/4248328

Comment: @max: Please check my answer

Comment: @ Hamza Mohamed  I want to get wherebetween check records leaveIDs

Answer (score 1):

it will return leave id because you are selecting `leaveId`. if you want all data with `leaveId` remove the select part.

Comment: Yes, but It doesn't check wherebetween. I want to get leaveIds after check wherebetween.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$fromdate = '2018-04-09';
$todate = '2018-04-28';
$dt = array($fromdate, $todate);
return DB::table('leaves')
  ->select('leaveId')
  ->whereRaw('from BETWEEN "'.$fromdate.'" AND "'.$todate.'" OR to BETWEEN "'.$fromdate .'" AND "'.$todate.'"')
  ->get();
```

Comment: pass this error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from BETWEEN "2018-04-09" AND "2018-04-28" OR to BETWEEN "2018-04-09" AND "2018-' at line 1 (SQL: select `leaveId` from `leaves` where (from BETWEEN "2018-04-09" AND "2018-04-28" OR to BETWEEN "2018-04-09" AND "2018-04-28")

Comment: @max: Please check i have updated my answer

Comment: Doing a raw query with a column called `from` could be tricky as it is a reserved word in most SQL DBMS and most likely needs special formatting, which is normally done by the corresponding SQL grammar if non-raw methods are used.