# Laravel wherebetween with orwherebetween

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I have written a Laravel query. I am using `whereBetween` and `orWhereBetween` along with a `where` statement on a column named 'shareable', which should return one row.
But this query does not take `where` condition into consideration. It took only `whereBetween` and `orWhereBetween`. What can be the reason.

my query

```
$childs = Program::whereIn('id', $programs_by_date)
                ->where('shareable', '=','1')
                ->wherebetween('starting_date', [$new_start_date,$new_end_date])
                ->orwherebetween('ending_date', [$new_start_date,$new_end_date])
                ->orderBy('starting_date')
                ->get();
```

`->where('shareable', '=','1')` return 0 rows. What can be the reason.

`shareable` type is enum

Comment: Could you please explain what you're trying to achieve from this query? It might be that there is a better way of doing what are you're doing now.

Comment: @WebGuy i am trying to get list of programs where starting_date or ending_date between $new_start_date and $new_end_date if only shareable equals to 1.$programs_by_date is an array.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should wrap whereBetween & orWhereBetween in where. Try this:

```
$childs = Program::whereIn('id', $programs_by_date)
            ->where('shareable', '=','1')
            ->where(function($query) use ($new_start_date, $new_end_date){
                  $query->whereBetween('starting_date', [$new_start_date,$new_end_date])
                        ->orWhereBetween('ending_date', [$new_start_date,$new_end_date]);
                })
            ->orderBy('starting_date')
            ->get();
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Don't forget to add a semicolon at the end of line number 5

Answer (score -2):

You Should try this

```
$child = Program::whereIn('id', $programs_by_date)
                ->where('shareable', '=','1')
                ->whereRaw("( starting_date BETWEEN '".$new_start_date."' AND '".$new_end_date."' OR ending_date BETWEEN '".$new_start_date."' AND '".$new_end_date."' ")
                ->orderBy('starting_date')
                ->get();
```

Comment: you'll get error when you try this " Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string"

Comment: This example is open to SQL Injection, instead should use parameter binds available on the whereRaw.
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods